# Saving user input in Multidimentional array

Tags: java

I want to make an application that takes (Username,password,Phone No.,And E-mail) from user, but I can't save the string values of user input how can i save the user input if I want to take many usernames or passwords.....etc?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner o = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a[] = new String[10000];
    String g[] = new String[10000];
    String k[] = new String[10000];
    String l[] = new String[10000];
    for (int rr = 0;; rr++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Username : ");
            a[i] = o.nextLine();
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < g.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Password : ");
            g[j] = o.nextLine();
            break;
        }
        for (int s = 0; s < k.length; s++) {
            System.out.println("E-Mail : ");
            k[s] = o.nextLine();
            break;
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < l.length; r++) {
            System.out.println("Phone number : ");
            l[r] = o.nextLine();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "save?" Do you mean you want to store a file in the filesystem that has all of the strings in it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you first make a model class for the User. So something like this:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public User(String name, String password, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
    // getters and setters for above fields
}
```

And then in your main you could just create a List for your Users like this:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then when you get input from the user you create one and add him to the list:

```
User adam = new User(name, password, phone, email);
users.add(adam);
```

If you want to get the user there is a get method:

```
adam = users.get(0);
```

Comment: but could you tell me how can i get the input from user to full the list?

Comment: You already did this by using Scanner. I don't know what exactly you want to achieve. If you want to add users in your application the best way is to use a database where you will store their information. Also using JFrames would be better for it than raw text.